# How do I get the selected option and store it in variable in python?

Tags: python

I want to get the selected option from the dict and manipulate it but when I print the variable it prints none.

```
def play():
    switcher = {
        1: "Rock",
        2: "Paper",
        3: "Scissors"}
    print(switcher)  
    i = input("Enter Your Choice: ") 
    s = switcher.get(i)
    print(s)


play()
```

Comment: `i` is a string since this is the return type of `input()`. Try `switcher.get(int(i))`. Ideally, though you would change the keys as strings or have better handling in case you can't convert the input as a `int`.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `switcher.get(i)`, the variable `i` is a string, whereas it should be an int. This explains your problem.
As a solution, I suggest you first to check if the input value is correct (and if not, repeat the question), then to convert it into an int, as follows:

```
def play():
    switcher = {
        1: "Rock",
        2: "Paper",
        3: "Scissors"}
    print(switcher)
    while True:
        i = input("Enter Your Choice: ")
        if i in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            i = int(i)
            break;
    s = switcher.get(i)
    print(s)

play()
```